# Laravel Image ( Working on store image )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, image-uploading

I am working on a laravel store image function. Fortunately it is working. But my problem is when I'm trying to upload atleast 20+ images. It only stores the first 20 images.

My question is, is there any settings that restricts my code to upload 20+ more files ?

Here is my code

```
public function storeImages($keycode, $projectsID){
    if(!empty($_FILES[$keycode]['name']) && isset($_FILES[$keycode]) && is_array($_FILES[$keycode]['name'])):
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES[$keycode]['name']); $i++):
            $filename = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9A-Z\.]/","_",$_FILES[$keycode]['name'][$i]);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$keycode]['tmp_name'][$i],"uploads/projects/".$filename); //stores original size
            try{
                if(trim($filename) != ""){
                    $img = \Image::make("uploads/projects/".$filename); //opens the original sizes
                    $img->resize(200,200); // resize original
                    $img->save('uploads/projects/200x200_'.$filename); // save resize images
                    $new = array();
                    $new['id'] = \App\Helper\ModelHelper::uuid();
                    $new['project_id'] = $projectsID;
                    $new['type'] = "BEFORE";
                    $new['img_name'] = $filename;
                    DB::table("projects_photos")->insert($new);
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){

            }
        endfor;
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php.ini

```
; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Change this and restart apache/nginx server

Comment: sorry for being dumb. I just saw my inifile configuration using `phpinfo()` that says `max_file_uploads` is `20`. My question. where can i find the `php.ini` in my laravel project?

Comment: in phpinfo() result, there is `Loaded Configuration File` . in this php.ini path specified

Comment: Thank you just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function Uploaduserimage($input=array(),$request){

if ($request->hasFile('userimg') && $request->file('userimg')->isValid()){ 
          $image = $request->file('userimg');
           $image_ext =  $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $imagetxt= array('gif','png','bmp','jpeg','jpg');
            if(!in_array( $image_ext,$imagetxt)){ 
                return false;  
            }
            else{ 
                $folderPath =  base_path()."/public/your image path"; 
                if(!is_dir($folderPath))  {
                    mkdir($folderPath,0777,true);
                    chmod($folderPath,0777);
                    $folderPath = $folderPath;
                } else {
                    $folderPath = $folderPath;
                }
                $image_Path=$folderPath;
                $newimg_name = substr(mt_rand(),0,5).time().".".$image_ext; 
                $request->file('userimg')->move($image_Path, $newimg_name);

                if(!empty($newimg_name))
                $obj->image=$newimg_name; 
                if($obj->save()){
                    return true;}
                 else 
                     return false; 
            }     
    }
 }
```